# How to get the global setting in Host.json file of a Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, settings

i have some settings in host.json file. I know that is globla settings for function app. I can get it on local but in production.

In local, i have this work
var maxDequeueCount=config.GetSection("extensions:queues:maxDequeueCount").Value;

Anyone tell me how to read setting from host.json file?

Thank you

var maxDequeueCount=config.GetSection("extensions:queues:maxDequeueCount").Value;

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var config = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
string maxAutoRenewDuration = config.GetSection("AzureFunctionsJobHost:extensions:serviceBus:messageHandlerOptions:maxAutoRenewDuration").Value;
```

Comment: What is the dependency of builder?

Comment: We use `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection.FunctionsStartup` that provides the `IFunctionsHostBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

The [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json) metadata file contains global configuration options that affect all functions for a function app.

**Other function app configuration options are managed in your [app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings).**

Settings in the **local.settings.json** file are only used by Functions tools **when running locally**

**Regarding your query :**  You could config it in your **appsettings blade** of the azure function

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want to get those settings during the runtime. For example, i want to get the maxDequeueCount for some logic.

Comment: Yes add in App seettings and then get that setting by var customSetting =  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CustomSetting", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);                                                                           https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/environment-variables?tabs=csharp#accessing-environment-variables

Comment: the problem here is that we have 2 setting file, the one you said and another is host.Json. We can change the setting in Host.Json

Comment: To read the settings , you need to put in App settings blade not in host.json

Comment: but we have 2 kind of setting here. host.json is global setting, it cannot put in app setting. Global setting mean the setting before the app start

Comment: I believe what Dixit is suggesting is that you add your maxDequeueCount as an app setting, then reference the app setting from your host.json using a placeholder like so:

```{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "queues": {
            "maxDequeueCount": "%DEQUEUE_COUNT_APP_SETTING%"
        }
    }
}
```