# Azure Functions: how do you read the settings in host.json at runtime?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, settings

Is there a way to read the host settings in the host.json file at runtime?
Say you have a host file like this:

```js
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 16
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do you then read the `maxConcurrentCalls` setting from your C# code?

It would be preferred if the default values were included too. You should get the same values as printed in the console on startup:

```
[28-01-2020 09:16:06] LoggerFilterOptions
[28-01-2020 09:16:06] {
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "MinLevel": "None",
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "Rules": [
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]     {
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]       "ProviderName": null,
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]       "CategoryName": null,
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]       "LogLevel": null,
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]     },
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]     {
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]       "CategoryName": null,
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]       "LogLevel": "None",
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]       "Filter": null
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]     },
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]     {
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]       "CategoryName": null,
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]       "LogLevel": null,
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]     }
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   ]
[28-01-2020 09:16:06] }
[28-01-2020 09:16:06] FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
[28-01-2020 09:16:06] {
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "BatchSize": 1000,
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "IsEnabled": true
[28-01-2020 09:16:06] }
[28-01-2020 09:16:06] SingletonOptions
[28-01-2020 09:16:06] {
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
[28-01-2020 09:16:06] }
[28-01-2020 09:16:06] ServiceBusOptions
[28-01-2020 09:16:06] {
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "PrefetchCount": 0,
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "MessageHandlerOptions": {
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]     "AutoComplete": true,
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]     "MaxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00",
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]     "MaxConcurrentCalls": 192
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   },
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "SessionHandlerOptions": {
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]     "AutoComplete": true,
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]     "MaxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00",
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]     "MaxConcurrentSessions": 2000,
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]     "MessageWaitTimeout": "00:01:00"
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   },
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "BatchOptions": {
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]     "MaxMessageCount": 1000,
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]     "OperationTimeout": "00:01:00",
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]     "AutoComplete": true
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   }
[28-01-2020 09:16:06] }
[28-01-2020 09:16:06] HttpOptions
[28-01-2020 09:16:06] {
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": false,
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "MaxConcurrentRequests": -1,
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "MaxOutstandingRequests": -1,
[28-01-2020 09:16:06]   "RoutePrefix": "api"
[28-01-2020 09:16:06] }
```

Comment: You can use it from `local.settings.json` for getting it in runtime

Comment: I specifically want to know the settings from host.json. These are not my settings and shouldn't live in my local.settings.json file.

Comment: Side note: it is possible to see the settings (at least locally) on startup, as they are all printed in the terminal.

Comment: @MikkelR.Lund Here is a template for host.json(Function v2 or later): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json

Comment: @BowmanZhu Right, but that doesn't show me which setting is actually being used on runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the global setting in Host.json file of a Azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487309/how-to-get-the-global-setting-in-host-json-file-of-a-azure-function)

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var config = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
        string maxConcurrentCalls = config.GetSection("AzureFunctionsJobHost:extensions:serviceBus:messageHandlerOptions:maxConcurrentCalls").Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a full example of this? Not sure what builder is from you snippet?

Comment: Need to add annotation for this to work: `[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]` per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection)

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in .net6.0

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

For your requirements, I think you can design a function to read and parse the json value. I think you understand that the format of the host.json file is fixed, so I can give a simple example here:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace HttpTrigger
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        public static string GetFileJson(string filepath)
        {
            string json = string.Empty;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")))
                {
                    json = sr.ReadToEnd().ToString();
                }
            }
            return json;
        }
        //Read Json Value
        public static string ReadJson()
        {
            string jsonfile = "host.json";
            string jsonText = GetFileJson(jsonfile);
            JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
            string value = ((JObject)jsonObj["extensions"])["serviceBus"]["messageHandlerOptions"]["maxConcurrentCalls"].ToString();
            return value;
        }
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string value = ReadJson();

            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            return name != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body" + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

You can see that I got the value of maxConcurrentCalls inside host.json. The function part above the Azure Function body is what you need.

Comment: This would only work with values set in the host.json file, right? The settings do have default values, which normally won't be present in the file.